# Fontawesome 5 in Android, 3 files

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

For quite some time I used fontawesome-webfont.ttf ,but now for quite some time FontAwesome 5 came out, and I can't really seem how to use it. From what I understand they splitted this file in multiple files. Now you have 3 files: regular, solid, brand. What I'm trying to do is to combine all 3 of them, or that the right file is used for the right icon, because in Android I have a FontManager, that handles fonts from 1 ttf file, and then I have custom textviews and button class that get fonts from this manager, so I don't have to set them in Activities or Fragments.

```
object FontManager {

    val ROOT = "fonts/"
    val FONTAWESOME = ROOT + "fontawesome-webfont.ttf"

    fun getTypeface(context: Context, font: String): Typeface {
        return Typeface.createFromAsset(context.assets, font)
    }

    fun markAsIconContainer(v: View, typeface: Typeface) {
        if (v is ViewGroup) {
            for (i in 0 until v.childCount) {
                val child = v.getChildAt(i)
                markAsIconContainer(child, typeface)
            }
        } else if (v is TextView) {
            v.typeface = typeface
        }
    }

}
```

Example of TextViewWithFont:

```
class TextViewFont : android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView {

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle) {
        init(context)
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {
        init(context)
    }

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        init(context)
    }

    private fun init(context: Context) {
        val iconFont = FontManager.getTypeface(context, FontManager.FONTAWESOME)
        FontManager.markAsIconContainer(this, iconFont)
    }
}
```

As you can see that FONTAWESOME, gets ttf file and then it manages it. Is there any way to combine all 3 ttf files so I could use all icons that FontAwesome provides. The hard way is that i use normal textview and for each icon appropriate resource (solid/brand/regular).
How do I combine them in Android?

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays most of the fonts has variations like the one you have. So you can convert your font manager to handle multiple files like below.

FontManager - FontCache.class

```
public class FontCache {


private static String[] fonts = {"ProximaNova-Reg.otf","ProximaNova-Light.otf","ProximaNova-Medium.otf","ProximaNova-Sbold.otf","ProximaNova-Bold.otf","ProximaNova-Light-It.otf","ProximaNova-Medium-It.otf"};
private static HashMap<String, Typeface> fontCache = new HashMap<>();

public static Typeface getTypeface(int fontPos, Context context) {
    String font = "fonts/"+fonts[fontPos];
    Typeface typeface = fontCache.get(font);

    if (typeface == null) {
        try {
            typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), font);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }

        fontCache.put(font, typeface);
    }

    return typeface;
  }
}
```

And your CustomTextView class

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        applyCustomFont(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        applyCustomFont(context, attrs);
    }

    private void applyCustomFont(Context context,AttributeSet attrs) {
        int fontPos = getFont(context,attrs);
        Typeface customFont = FontCache.getTypeface(fontPos, context);
        setTypeface(customFont);
    }

    private int getFont(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs){
        TypedArray a = ctx.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomTextView);
        int customFont = a.getInt(R.styleable.CustomTextView_customFont,0);
        return customFont;
    }
}
```

create attrs.xml file inside res/values folder. This file contains the font variations. you can specify whichever number of fonts that you needed.

**res/values/attrs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="CustomTextView">
        <attr name="customFont">
            <enum name="regular" value="0" />
            <enum name="light" value="1" />
            <enum name="medium" value="2" />
            <enum name="semibold" value="3" />
            <enum name="bold" value="4" />
            <enum name="light_it" value="5" />
            <enum name="medium_it" value="6" />
        </attr>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Your Textview inside layout

```
 <com.t365.android.customview.CustomTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="test"
                app:customFont="semibold" // semibold variantion of your font is applied here // if nothing is specified here it takes base variant of your custom font
                />
```

If you don't specify any font, it will take the base variant of your font (say regular in your Fontawesome as mentioned in question), which we have done it in CustomTextview class.

```
private int getFont(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs){
        TypedArray a = ctx.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomTextView);
        int customFont = a.getInt(R.styleable.CustomTextView_customFont,0); // by default we are asking fontManger to take 0 variant.
        return customFont;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

*I wrote some code to simplify using *FontAwesome* in android apps. (I implemented `FontAwesome` as a class extending `AppCompatTextView` - GitHub: [finnmglas/fontawesome-android](https://github.com/finnmglas/fontawesome-android))*

---

When I switched to *FontAwesome 5*, I had the same issue.

I implemented the following function to dynamically switch the icon type of an Icon:

```kotlin
fun setIconType(iconType : String){
  type = iconType

  typeface = when (type) {
    "regular" -> Typeface.createFromAsset(context!!.assets,"fontawesome/fa-regular-400.ttf")
    "solid" -> Typeface.createFromAsset(context!!.assets,"fontawesome/fa-solid-900.ttf")
    "brands" -> Typeface.createFromAsset(context!!.assets,"fontawesome/fa-brands-400.ttf")
    else -> Typeface.createFromAsset(context!!.assets,"fontawesome/fa-solid-900.ttf")
}
```

The function just changes the icons `typeface` by selecting the right `.ttf` file that contains the icons of the selected type.

Extra: Here is an example android Activity showing you how it works: [view on GitHub](https://github.com/finnmglas/fontawesome-android/tree/master/examples/2%20-%20Icon%20Types)

---

*Works great for me in my apps and I noticed some other people also started using the `FontAwesome` class I wrote.*